# Why isn't cv2.filter2D() working as expected?

Tags: python, image, blur, opencv

I'm trying to get a **blur effect**. I know I can do it by using **cv2.blur()** but when I use **cv2.filter2D()** it doesn't seem to work that good.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("img.jpeg")

bimg = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))

k3 = np.ones((5, 5), np.float32)
kimg = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, k3)

cv2.imshow("O", img)
cv2.imshow("B", bimg)
cv2.imshow("K", kimg)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRc6s.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to provide a description when including an image, for accessibility reasons, or for search-ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't want to change the average of the image, so we need to ensure that the sum of the kernel is 1.

Instead of `k3 = np.ones((5, 5), np.float32)`, use:

```
k3 = np.ones((5, 5), np.float32) / 25
```

---

Why using `ones(5, 5)` kernel results a white image?

Assume for example that the value of all the pixels of `img` equal `100`.

Applying `cv2.filter2D` (discrete 2D convolution) For every pixel:

`kimg[y,x] = img[y-2, x-2]*1 + img[y-2, x-1]*1 + img[y-2, x]*1 + ... + img[y+2, x+2]`
= `100*1 + 100*1 + ... + 100*1` = `100*25` = `2500`.

(The value of all the pixels of `kimg` is going to be `2500`).

Since the type of `kimg` is `uint8`, all values above 255 are clipped to 255, so 2500 is clipped to 255, and 255 applies white color.

Comment: Thank you for your very well explained answer.